# Alternate for TitlePart in Orchard not properly applied to actual rendering of the Title

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I want to override the way a title (TitlePart or Parts_Title) is rendered for a specific content type and made an alternate using the shape tracing tool. The funny thing is that whatever I change to the alternate the title is still rendered with the same html as before. In the shape tracing tool however the "Template" tab shows the modified template.

What could be going on here and how do I properly fix it?

EDIT

Same problem also occurs with body. where the template `@Model.Html lalala` doesn't show the text "lalala".

Comment: Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing: what rendering of the title are you trying to change? I'm asking because a title can typically be rendered in several places, including the title tag in the page head. Different rendering is handled by different templates.
It looks like we are talking about the same thing but let's be sure.
Second question: where did you put the alternate template and what did you name it?

Comment: It is the on page rendering within the content zone. I generated the alternate to my theme using the Shape Tracing plugin. The alternate is named `Parts.Title-Hoofdcategorie-pagina.cshtml` and resides in the  Views folder of my theme.

Comment: What do Hoofdcategorie and pagina represent? Are they two different things or two parts of one category name? If the latter, then that is probably your problem: you should not have a dash in the category name. I suppose there should be validation there but you can fix by removing that dash.

Comment: Hoofdcategorie-pagina is the name of a content type. I can see why that is a problem.    
Why does shape tracing still think the alternate is applied when you view the applied template though?

Comment: It probably doesn't expect it, which would be a bug, that you may want to file. Still you have a workaround here.

Comment: Here: http://orchard.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create